# How to get Firebase children in Android mentioned in a ArrayList? [Android]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, nosql

I have a Firebase project in which there are multiple events.

[image: list of events]

And I have a list of favourite events like

Favourites: [2017071227185209, 2017071271534874, 2017072819680542, 2017073111392921]

Now my method to get only these events is

```
Query userRef = mDatabase.child("Events");
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
              {

            if(Favourites.contains(snapshot.getValue().toString))
                 {
                   //The event is favourite, get data here
                 }
              }


        }
```

How should I get the data in a firebase recycler view? The only method I know is putting an appropriate query which does all the filtering for you. Is there any appropriate query for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
List<Event> eventList =  new ArrayList<>();

for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   Event event = data.getValue(Event.class);
   if (event.isFavorite()){ // or change your logic here
      eventList.add(event);
   }
}
```

Comment: To do this, I will have to discard the Firebase recycler view and create my own. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

I recomand you using this method:

```
void checkIfEventExists(String event) {
    Query userRef = mDatabase.child("Events");
    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             if(dataSnapshot.child(event).exists()) {
                 //get event data
             } 
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.